# Change one given cell UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to change just one cell programmatically in my CollectionView. I've tried this code, but that's not work me. Nothing change in my cell number 6. It's probably because i don't do the great thing.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = wantSeeCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "wantSeeCell", for: indexPath) as? accountCollectionViewCell
    
    if (indexPath.item == 6) {
        cell?.posterCell.image = nil
        cell?.buttonCell.titleLabel?.text = "En voir +"
    }
    
    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to grab the 6th element, you have to extract that from the row method.
Try this:

`if(indexPath.row == 5)`.

Note that the first row is 0, so you have to subtract 1 to get the row.

Also keep in mind that you will need an else clause to reset the properties of the cell back to its original values since cells get reused. Otherwise, you may see some strange results when scrolling through the collection.

Comment: This answer is only partially correct. You need an `else` to reset the properties for all other rows since cells get reused.

Comment: Good call @rmaddy will update the answer to include pertinent information.